# Taxonomy bulk edit in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have been trying to find a good, working method to do some bulk taxonomy operations in Drupal 7.

The Administration Views module doesn't appear to work - I just get page not found errors when trying to access any of the views.

So, I have been trying to follow this guide here: http://learnbythedrop.com/drop/166 . However, this is for Drupal 6 and I can't find the corresponding options in Drupal 7. There is no Style option in the view dialog, and Format contains:
Grid
 HTML list
 Jump menu
 Quicktabs
 Table
 Unformatted list, But nothing for VBO.

Can someone help here? This is where drupal really falls down IMO - total lack of up to date documentation and lots of time spent trying to find modules to do simple things which should be in core.

Comment: I've now watched the video here: http://nodeone.se/blogg/views-bulk-operations . I've found the bulk operations field to add, but there doesn't seem to be any taxonomy related actions. Is there really no decent way of doing this in d7?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a really easy way to do this with d7 yet. [Views bulk operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) will probably be your best bet for the future, as there is work going on to provide this functionality (see: http://drupal.org/node/1142062).

In the meantime, vbo does work with the [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module, so it looks like it might be possible to use rules and vbo together to accomplish bulk taxonomy updates, although I don't think this is trivial. This screencast: http://vimeo.com/26884701 and this comment: http://drupal.org/node/1057158#comment-4792118 might help to get you started.

Comment: It seems like http://drupal.org/node/1142062#comment-4896268 might just work. I'll give it a try! Thanks a lot for the help, have been doing serious damage to my forehead trying to figure out how to do this one!

Answer (score 1):

VBO now has a Modify Field Value option which you need to enable through Views.  The options are in the Bulk Operations FIELD.  Although at the moment there's an issue where updating taxonomy term fields for multiple nodes at the same time results in duplicate taxonomy terms with different TIDs added to your vocabulary.